# How to convert pipe separated data to vertical format data

Tags: shell, text-formatting

I have a scenario where want data to be stored in file in vertical format

below is the data

```
143|2345|3456|4567|2345|3457|2019-12-28 12:00:01|2019-12-28
```

After applying my below logic my data is in below format

```
cat demo.txt |rev| cut -d'|' -f3-|rev|cut -d'|' -f2-
```

It gives me the required output like below

```
2345|3456|4567|2345|3457
```

But now the issue is i want the required output data in vertical format to a text file

like below in file

```
2345
3456
4567
2345
3457
```

Comment: Do you have a file with several such rows in? Is the number of columns consistent? Seems to me the answers posted so far retain the first field, or remove the last 2 fields from only the final record, or other kinds of bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '|' '\n'
```

will convert each pipe to a newline and should do the trick.

```
echo "143|2345|3456|4567|2345|3457|2019-12-28 12:00:01|2019-12-28" | tr '|' '\n'
```

Or maybe in your case you're looking for

```
cat file | tr '|' '\n' > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with multiple rows, and with a variable number of fields, this removes col1 and the last two columns, and puts remaining columns vertically.

```
awk '-F|' '{ for (f = 2; f <= NF - 2; ++f) print $(f); }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original data and GNU `head`:

```
$ tr '|' '\n' <demo.txt | head -n -2
143
2345
3456
4567
2345
3457
```

The `tr` command just changes `|`-characters into newlines.  Note that `tr` only reads from standard input, so you will need to redirect into it.

If GNU `head` is given a negative number of lines, it trims that number of lines off from the end of the data.

Alternatively, with a single call to `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(|[^|]*\)\{2\}$//; y/|/\n/' demo.txt
143
2345
3456
4567
2345
3457
```

Here, the substitution will remove the last two `|`-delimited fields by matching the two `|`-characters and the strings after each, then the `y` command changes each remaining `|` into a newline (just like `tr` does in the first solution).

With `sed -E`, it may be a bit more readable (note that we have to escaep one of the `|`-characters now):

```
sed -E 's/(\|[^|]*){2}$//; y/|/\n/' demo.txt
```